Directly change the data pins on USB?
Using the usb-a pinout Data+ & Data- can you manually toggle between 0 and 1 (powered and not) or take in input using pyserial by just using the Data+ & Data-? Could this be done with usb-c even?
I want to be able to not use arduino/any microcontrollers to communicate with the USB, just software.

This kind of low level interaction is not supported by typical USB hardware, drivers and the operation system. There are tricks though that allow you to pull up the data lines to force a reaction from the OS. In any case to unspecific to be a good SO question.
